# Is this a proper MySql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

Im trying to get the  first 100 rows consisting of First Name, Last Name, Department Name, Title, Salary from the employee database but not sure if Im doing it correctly. I tried the query below and it seems to work but doesn't feel right specially since there are no ON statements for the last 2 joins. Is it correct and is there a more efficient way I can perform this query.

This is the link to the database tables graph to give you a idea of the database.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/images/employees-schema.png

My query that seems to work:

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, dpn.dept_name, t.title, s.salary
FROM employees e, dept_emp dp
INNER JOIN departments dpn
ON dp.dept_no = dpn.dept_no
INNER JOIN salaries s
INNER JOIN titles t
LIMIT 100;
```

I tried the code below but kept getting error "#1054 - Unknown column 'e.emp_no' in 'on clause' " starting for the second to last ON statement.

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, dpn.dept_name, t.title, s.salary
FROM employees e, dept_emp dp
INNER JOIN departments dpn
ON dp.dept_no = dpn.dept_no
INNER JOIN salaries s
ON e.emp_no = salaries.emp_no
INNER JOIN titles t
ON e.emp_no = t.emp_no
LIMIT 100;
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you (think you) mean by "the first 100 rows"? Tables have no order until an outermost SORT BY. What does "tried the query below" mean? What does "seems to work" mean? And "doesn't feel right"? Please read and act on [ask] and [mcve]. And please edit in  tables & DDL as text, don't link to.

Answer (score 2):

You have no join clause between  e table and dp table eg:

```
  SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, dp.dept_name, t.title, s.salary
  FROM employees e
  INNER JOIN dept_emp dp on e.emp_no = dp.emp_no
  INNER JOIN departments dpn  ON dp.dept_no = dpn.dept_no
  INNER JOIN salaries s  ON e.emp_no = s.emp_no
  INNER JOIN titles t ON e.emp_no = t.emp_no
  LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback i think there is a small error on your code "INNER JOIN dept_emp dp on e.emp_no = dp.dept_no"  the ON statement should be "ON e.emp_no = dp.emp_no". Since we are comparing emp_no's and in your code we are comparing emp_no to dept_no.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, departments.dept_name, titles.title, salaries.salary
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN dept_emp
ON e.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no
INNER JOIN departments
ON dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no
INNER JOIN titles
ON e.emp_no = titles.emp_no
INNER JOIN salaries
ON e.emp_no = salaries.emp_no
LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "On" clause in inner join is optional. If you do not have "On" clause it means a "cross join". 
If what you want is inner join, then you should have an "On" clause and specify which columns should equate.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.first_name, 
       e.last_name, 
       departments.dept_name, 
       titles.title, 
       salaries.salary 
FROM   employees e 
       LEFT JOIN dept_emp 
              ON e.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no 
       LEFT JOIN departments 
               ON dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no 
       LEFT JOIN titles 
             ON e.emp_no = titles.emp_no 
       LEFT JOIN salaries 
               ON e.emp_no = salaries.emp_no 
LIMIT  100;
```

try this one too because

> INNER JOIN: returns rows when there is a match in all tables.
>
> LEFT JOIN: returns all rows from the left table, even if there are no matches in the right table.